# Regarding the power series, $1-{x\over 2}+{x^2\over 3}-{x^3\over4}+\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across this power series while solving a problem.

$$1-{x\over 2}+{x^2\over 3}-{x^3\over4}+\dots$$

I calculated its radius of convergence and it turned out to be $1$.

Does this power series represent some well function in the given interval of convergence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $1\ge x>-1,$

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}3-\dfrac{x^3}4+\cdots$$

Divide both sides by $x$ assuming $x\ne0$